# What can eating pink mold do to a healthy person (someone whose immune system is not weakened)?

Tags: mycology

I've tried searching it up, but my research has yielded nothing very specific.

The following website was the closest I came to finding something about pink mold on bread. It, however, said nothing about the effects of eating pink mold (https://moldcleans.com/pink-mold-on-bread/)

I also found another website, https://lookmold.com/detect/type/pink-mold, which states that healthy (people without compromised/weakened immune systems) people don't get sick right away from exposure to pink mold. Other sources, however, claim that only people with compromised immune systems will get infected by a fungal infection. Hence my question: what can eating mold do to a healthy (healthy immune system) person?

Edit: Thanks to all who responded! The advice was very helpful. I have also edited my question to fit the rules, for I am still curious about the effects of pink mold on a healthy person.

Comment: Just fyi your second linked source says "It’s not actually mold! That’s right, it’s actually bacteria. For the sake of this article we will refer to it as pink mold. The name of the bacteria is called *Serratia marcescens*." It's great that you did some research before posting your question here. It may not be true that what you saw in the muffin is the same as what is commonly found on bathroom walls. You should save all traces of the muffin you ate and any other muffins and consider seeing a doctor. Stack Exchange is not the right place to ask real personal health-related issues.

Comment: Was the patch fuzzy? If not it wasn't mold. But it could be pink yeast which can be found in spoiled dood according to wikipedia. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodotorula_glutinis

Comment: I reopened this question because I had previously unilaterally closed it for being a request for personal medical advice. I still think it could use a bit more clarity and prior research to be a good Biology.SE question, but I'll leave it up to the community.